# Custom-defined hexadecimal colors in ggplot: problems with factor levels

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am simply trying to plot the correct colors specified for each category in a data frame, but the labels are off.

This is an example of the data:

```
dat = data.frame(value1=c(10,2,4,10,5,6,7,8), value2=c(12,2,6,7,3,5,6,19), class=c("D", "A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "D","B"), color=c("#B15928", "#E52829", "#79C360", "#E52829", "#B89B74", "#B15928", "#B15928", "#79C360")
```

And the code works fine I think for coloring but then the labelling in the legend in my data is not correct:

This is incorrectly labelling the legend:

```
 ggplot(dat, aes(value1, value2)) + geom_point(aes(colour = color)) + scale_color_manual(values = levels(dat$color), labels = levels(dat$class))

 ggplot(dat, aes(value1, value2)) + geom_point(aes(colour = color)) + scale_color_manual(values = levels(dat$color), labels = dat$class)
```

I guess it has to do with factor levels, but what is the correct way to do this, i.e. having a data frame with categories and colors based on the categories? I tried defining factor and levels of color based on the class, and the opposite, but I can't get it to work. I have also tried naming each category with e.g. values = c("A"="#E52829",..)
Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Could you make it a bit more explicit exactly what you are looking to obtain?

Comment: Yes, your factor levels are getting messed up ... you can see the orders are not what you expect  by looking at`with(dat, table(class, color))`.

Comment: The usual way is too map to a column (class) rather than having a column of colours... so `ggplot(dat, aes(value1, value2, colour = class)) + geom_point(size=8) +   scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow"),  labels = levels(dat$class))` (the labels isnt really needed here) . Although i prefer to use     ``ggplot(dat, aes(value1, value2, colour = class)) + geom_point(size=8) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c(`A`="red", `B`="blue", `C`="green", `D`="yellow"))``. (again the colours dont need to be named but it does keep it clear)

Comment: Wait, what's wrong with just `ggplot(dat, aes(value1, value2)) + geom_point(aes(colour = class))`?

Comment: ``ggplot(dat, aes(value1, value2, colour = class)) + geom_point(size=8) + 
  scale_color_manual(values = c(`B`="blue", `C`="red", `A`="green", `D`="yellow"))``     shows the benefit of naming the colour vector

Comment: @alistaire; because the op wants to map specific colours to class and not just use the default. Really the question is how to use `scale_`

Comment: A scale doesn't take as many values as you have rows - you only need one value per unique level. Unlike base graphics, having actual color values in the data frame is pointless for ggplot. Just use `aes(color = class)` and set `values = ` your hex colors, one color per level.

Comment: Thank you! I see, so it is actually pointless to have color in the data frame, thanks so much for the help and clarification! I can't accept because they are comments, but thank you immensely! if I do this it works: ggplot(dat, aes(value1, value2)) + geom_point(aes(colour = class)) + scale_color_manual(values = c(`B`="#79C360", `C`="#B89B74", `A`="#E52829", `D`="#B15928"))

Comment: try `scale_colour_identity` (and `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in your data frame) `ggplot(dat, aes(value1, value2)) + geom_point(aes(colour = color)) + scale_color_identity(guide = 'legend')`